# Como detectar tab en un formulario en javascript

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber como crear un evento que conecte con un método que me permita detectar cuando un usuario dentro de un formulario presione la tecla tab o enter y luego de hacerlo me permita ejecutar alguna acción.

Comment: Hola, aunque ya te han dado una respuesta, recuerda que es importante que subas el código de lo que hayas intentado por tu cuenta. Puedes leer [ask] y [mcve]. De lo contrario tu pregunta no es bien recibida por la comunidad y de allí los votos negativos recibidos. Saludos

Comment: Intuyo que tal vez también vas a querer llamar a preventDefault, échale un ojo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De la siguiente manera lo puedes hacer, lo importante es saber cuál es el `keycode` asociado a la tecla que buscas.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  // ENTER detectado
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    // Código para la tecla ENTER
    console.log("Oprimiste la tecla ENTER");
  }
  
  // TAB detectado
  if (event.keyCode == 9) {
    // Código para la tecla TAB
    console.log("Oprimiste la tecla TAB");
  }

});
```

Te recomiendo que agregues el `eventListener` en el objeto que quieras manipular, además tienes los siguientes tipos de eventos que escuchan en diferentes momentos el accionar de una tecla, solo para que los tengas en cuenta en caso de que necesites uno de ellos en específico.

- keydown
- keypress
- keyup